# Retrieving Video Duration During Save Operation in Django Model

Tags: python, django

I’m attempting to extract the duration of a video file within the Django model’s save method. I plan to use the OpenCV library for this purpose. My current challenge is properly accessing the video file in the isOpened() method of OpenCV to ensure that I can extract the duration.

The problematic part seems to occur when I attempt to access the file during the execution of the super().save(*args, **kwargs) method, which I believe I need to call twice, once before and after obtaining the video duration, to ensure the file path is accessible to OpenCV.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
    if not self.pk:
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        path = self.content.path
        self.duration = get_video_duration(path)

    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: wrong tool. use ffmpeg/ffprobe or other libraries. OpenCV just happens to be able to read videos but it's not made for this. -- traceback required. [mre]